# How do I select a person only if their Id appears in another table?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

In the following LINQ statement, I'm trying to select people but only if their Id appears in another table (a join table). What am I missing?

In this example, I have a People table and a Contractors table. The Person's contactId may appear in the Contractors table. I want to grab the contactId of People that appear in the Contractors table.

```
var allPeople = People.Where(x => x.Contractors
                                   .Where(m=> m.ContactID == x.ContactID)
                                  .Select(x => x.ContactID));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Where` function must return a boolean expression. If I understand your question correctly, you only want people from the peoples table that are in the contractors table as well. Then we can ask just that: Give me a person if any contractor has that ID:

```
var allPeople = People.Where(x => x.Contractors
                                   .Any(m => m.ContactID == x.ContactID));
```

Comment: I started out using .Any() but it wasn't working. I may have been over-thinking the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about regular LINQ JOIN statement:

```
var peopleWithContact = People.Join(
    Contractors, 
    p => p.ContactId, // the field to join by from People table
    c => c.ContactId, // the field to join by from Contractors table
    (p, c) => p.ContactId); // the result if match; could be just p.
```